# What is the naming convention for theme region template files?

Tags: theming

I want a custom template for every theme region, but I'm not sure of the naming convention.
For example, with the following information the .info file, would **region--header.tpl.php** be a correct template name for the *Header* region?

```
regions[header] = 'Header' 
regions[sidebar_first] = 'Sidebar First'
regions[content] = 'Content'
regions[footer] = 'Footer'
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the naming scheme is **region--[region].tpl.php** where **[region]** is the region machine name defined in the theme info file. See [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) for more information. You will need to flush your theme registry cache for the template to take effect.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered your question, you should mark it answered for other readers.